# Is there a way to have Google Voice expose new SMS recipent's @txt.voice.google.com email address without a text response?

Tags: google-voice, google-voice-actions

After toggling on the "Forward messages to email" toggle in Google Voice settings SMS responses produce an email address that follows this template:

"sender's GV 10-digit phone number" . "recipient's 10-digit phone number" . "string of random characters"@txt.voice.google.com

You can then send an email to that email address which will show up in the Google Voice app and the recipient's phone as a text from the Google Voice sender's number.

Questions:

Is there any way to have Google Voice show the email address for a contact that has not responded to a GV text yet (ex: new contact)?

Potentially, sending a pseudo text that doesn't actually show up to the recipient but responds to GV exposing the @txt.voice.google.com email for the recipient?

Can only see @txt.voice.google.com after the initial SMS is replied to.